# How do I add (layer) a .wav audio file to a ProRes 422 HQ .mxf video without re-encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, premiere, video-editor, editing

Here's the detailed info of the .mxf video

```
General
Complete name                            : D:\R-2180634-1250074380.jpeg-gigapixel-low_res-scale-2_00x.mxf
Format                                   : MXF
Format version                           : 1.3
Format profile                           : OP-1a
Format settings                          : Closed / Complete
File size                                : 123 GiB
Duration                                 : 45 min 38 s
Overall bit rate                         : 387 Mb/s
Package name                             : Source Package
Encoded date                             : 2022-09-26 15:48:32.968
Writing application                      : Adobe Inc. Adobe Media Encoder 2.0.0.0.1
Writing library                          : win32 5.3.6.0.1

Video
ID                                       : 512
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422 HQ
Format settings, wrapping mode           : Frame
Codec ID                                 : 0D010301021C0100-0401020203060400
Duration                                 : 45 min 38 s
Bit rate                                 : 387 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 200 pixels
Height                                   : 1 078 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.113
Frame rate                               : 60.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 4.981
Stream size                              : 123 GiB (100%)
Writing library                          : adb0
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mxf -i in.wav -c copy out.mxf
```

The audio should be Linear PCM signed 16 or 24 bit at 48000 Hz.

Comment: Thank you for helping!